# How can I pass line breaks from a textarea via ajax to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Im using the back end of wordpress to allow the client to fill in a form and send the content of a text area in an email.

My problem here is that when I click send, the string from the text area converts to `Line1%0ALine2%0ALine3` (as a result of encodeURIComponent()) and posts that over to my PHP funciton. When this is sent out in the email thats literally what I get.

I know I need to decode / encode this in some way and I think Im nearly there.

So far my JS looks like this.

```
tinyMCE.triggerSave();
var messagetext = jQuery('textarea#emailMessage').val();
var newEmailForm = [];
var email = jQuery('input.email').val();
var title = jQuery('input.title').val();
var emailMessage = encodeURIComponent(messagetext);
newEmailForm.push([email,title,emailMessage]);

var datastring = {
        newEmailForm: newEmailForm,
        properties: properties
    };

jQuery(function(){
        jQuery.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            data:{
                action: 'elegantSendEmail',
                datastring: datastring
            },
            url: ajaxurl,
            success: function(data){
                alert(data);
            }
        })
    })
```

Using encodeURIComponent() posts the message text like this: `Line1%0ALine2%0ALine3`

My PHP Looks like.

```
function elegantSendEmail() {

  $to = $_POST['datastring']['newEmailForm'][0][0];
  $title = $_POST['datastring']['newEmailForm'][0][1];
  $messagetext = $_POST['datastring']['newEmailForm'][0][2], true);
  $properties = $_POST['datastring']['properties'];

  //Send the email and get a report back
  $sent = elegeantSend($to,$messagetext,$properties);

}
```

I just dont know how to convert the string into either `<br>` or `\n` etc.

TIA

Comment: What happens after `newEmailForm.push([email,title,emailMessage]);`? If you are sending data over POST AJAX request, call to `encodeURIComponent()` is not needed. PHP then automatically and correctly parse data into `$_POST`.

Comment: @Stphane Ive updated the snippet to include the remaining ajax function. Youll note Im also passing a second array.

Comment: Why are you using an object and a nested array to enclose the data? Try to remove `encodeURIComponent`, then put your data directly into the `data` object that you pass to the AJAX construct.

Comment: Wouldn't `urldecode('Line1%0ALine2%0ALine3');` in php help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **rawurldecode** function It will decode in php which is encoded with **encodeURIComponent()**

Answer (score -1):

you can use `str_replace`

example:

```
$messagetext = $_POST['datastring']['newEmailForm'][0][2], true);
$convertedMessageText = str_replace('%0A', "\n", $messagetext);
```

**PS**: this is for replace `%0A` to new line (like the question), not the other

Comment: This doesnt work. It doesnt replace all the other elements such as %20, quotes etc.

Comment: My answer for @AlexKnopp question ( `%0A` ), if you want another, please describe your question more detail